# Macro on cpp library included is ruining the rest of the codebase

Tags: c++

I'm working on an application that includes this library, let's call Snap.h.

I found that compilation fails if Snap.h is not the last on the includes statements. And on closer look, I find this code in a header file included by Snap.h

```
#define Try try {
#define Catch } catch (PExcept Except){ErrNotify(Except->GetMsgStr());}
#define CatchFull } catch (PExcept Except){ErrNotify(Except->GetStr());}
#define CatchAll } catch (...){}
```

Basically this lets try and catch blocks to be used as statements, like so

```
Try;
<some code>
Catch;
```

You can see how this is an issue, these generic macros collide with other libraries very easily.

Unfortunately this is tens of thousands of lines of very complicated code and the application I'm working on is built around this library. Its not easily changed.

Cpp is not my strong suit, is there a way to limit the effects of macros in an include?

Comment: `here a way to limit the effects of macros in an include?` `#undef`?

Comment: Putting it last in the include list is the first option. You could also introduce another header and put it at the end of you headers with #undef all these macros so your code will be guarded to reduce macros visibility #include "snap.h" <code> #include "stap_undef.h"

Comment: You simply don't need to use this style in your own code, let's hope it's always used correctly and consistently inside of the `Snap` stuff.

Comment: Such macro techniques are IMHO anti-patterns (for causing potentially exactly the problems you got). Finding such things in a header would make the code very suspicious to me. Any chance to throw this stuff away? I know what `try` and `catch` do in a C++ program but `Try;`? `Catch;`? I've never seen such things before. There are better ways to automate `try/catch` e.g. wrapping it in a function where the inner block (between `try` and `catch`) is provided as argument - e.g. with `std::function` or something even more clever.

Comment: `collide with other libraries` That means you have not one but (at least) two libraries which use similar dubious macros/names? In that case, there is a non-zero chance that just moving `snap.h` last "fixes" the compile but may introduce other obscure problems.

Comment: I think including a #undef header file anytime the Snap.h is included will work. In this particular example, Try was colliding with Fb's folly::Try, and a lot of thrift cpp autogenerated code. Thanks! One day if I'm here long enough will replace this library

Comment: _I think including a #undef header file anytime the Snap.h is included will work._ Even better: Write a new header file `fixedSnap.h` which does `#include<snap.h>` and then all necessary `#undef`s and then use only `#include "fixedSnap.h"` in the rest of your code. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I not a big fan of `#undef` things, because you never now what other bad stuff can slumber in that big header. I prefer isolating it in a "compilation barrier" i.e. only including it in a separate wrapper translation unit, which only redefines and forwards what you need. In the following example `Snap.h` redefines `BULLSHIT` to `std::terminate`, but as you can try, `main.cpp` can use the function in `Snap.h` without its version of `BULLSHIT`:

```
/*! @file main.cpp
 */
#include <iostream>

#define BULLSHIT
#include "snap_wrapper.h"

int main() {
    BULLSHIT
    std::cout << wrapper::nice_function() << "\n";
}


/*! @file Snap.h
 */
#ifndef UNTITLED5_SNAP_H
#define UNTITLED5_SNAP_H

#define BULLSHIT std::terminate();

int nice_function() {
    return 42;
}

#endif //UNTITLED5_SNAP_H

/*! @snap_wrapper.h
 */

#ifndef UNTITLED5_SNAP_WRAPPER_H
#define UNTITLED5_SNAP_WRAPPER_H

namespace wrapper{
int nice_function();
}

#endif //UNTITLED5_SNAP_WRAPPER_H

/*! @file snap_wrapper.c
 */

#include "snap_wrapper.h"
#include "Snap.h"

namespace wrapper {

        int nice_function() {
            return ::nice_function();
        }

}
```